# ShellExecute behaves differently for different projects

Tags: c++, windows, process

I know ShellExecute is platform dependent on Windows, but for the moment I'm using it to spawn an executable. In my test program it spawns in a new console window. Which is what I want. But when I add the same code to my game, it suddenly spawns the exe in the same console window.

Same line of code, but different behaviors. Here it is. Is it the last flag I'm setting wrong?

```
HINSTANCE Result=ShellExecute(NULL, "open", "GameMatch.exe",Args, NULL, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
```

Comment: Do both programs already have a console before you call ShellExecute?

Comment: Yes. And both are setup using the exact same way. Also, ShellExecute is called from inside a Class in both programs. So that's not it.

Comment: The only difference I can think of: in the test program, the code for the class that calls ShellExec is in the same folder as main.cpp. but in the real program, the cpp/h files are stored in a different folder